# Google mini ignoring sitemap

Tags: sitemap, search

I'm in the processing of setting up a Google Mini device to index our site which has a lot of dynamically generated content.  I've created a dynamic site.map file which lists all of the dynamic URL's.  This is currently being indexed by Google but seems to be ignored by the Google mini device.

I've added the site.map file into the "Start crawling from the following URL's".  When I view the crawl diagnostics the site.map file comes up but none of the dynamic URL's contained within the site.map are being indexed.  The Google mini device is only indexing 100 URL's whereas the site.map contains 10,000.

If I search for a phrase using the test centre the search results includes the site.map and not the URL it points to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the Google Mini's really blue?

Comment: Yes, both the box and the feeling it's giving me!

Comment: Cool. Well, not the headache it's giving you, but a blue server, would stand out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just had a consultant come in who has stated the Google Mini cannot index the URL's contained in a sitemap.xml file.  One alternative solution is to create a HTML page with all of the links within it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things from the top of my head:

1. Make sure the content type of your site map file is allowed to be indexed. html for example is allowed by default.
2. Make sure your site map is in the [XML site map format](http://www.sitemaps.org/).
3. If you have multiple collections defined, make sure that your site map file is reachable by the collection you expect it to be.

Comment: The site map is called site.map and is being indexed so I think that rules out #1.  The file is being indexed not the URL's it contains.
It conforms to #2 and has been submitted and indexed by the main Google search engine.  We've only got 1 collection so that rules out #3.  Any other suggestions?